# Visual Studio 2015 Web Install Proxy settings

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I had download web installer  vs_enterprise_ENU.exe , but it start and closed immediately

In logs I see

```
[0C40:03A0][2015-12-10T01:39:02]e000: Error 0x80190197: Failed to download http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615437&clcid=0x409; will try 2 more times.

[0C40:03A0][2015-12-10T01:39:02]e000: Error 0x80190197: Failed to download http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615437&clcid=0x409; will try 1 more times.

[0C40:03A0][2015-12-10T01:39:02]e000: Error 0x8007013d: Failed to format error message.

[0C40:03A0][2015-12-10T01:39:02]i000: Process exit code: 0x80190197 (-2145844841)
```

In browser with proxy settings this links opened successfully.
I suppose installer also needs proxy settings? How I can setup it ?